# How to assign class attributes in a loop Python

Tags: python, class

So I have a list:

`names = [“Bob”, “Guy”, “Super”, “Man”]`

I am trying to use a loop to assign Bob Guy as the firstname and lastname of user1, the next time the loop runs I want it to assign Super Man as the firstname and lastname of user2. I am using a class and the way I have set this up is by having a placeholder variable that grabs the 0 and 1 indexes of the list, and the next time to loop runs it grabs the 2 and 3 indexes. This works, however the problem is that my line says `user1 = ClassName(names[placeholder var])`. Meaning that each time the loop runs it is reassigning user1. Is there a way to change the name of “user1” to “user2” to “user3” (each time the loop runs) so it assigns the firstname and lastname attributes to my class as a new object for each person? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please, take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to ask a good question : Show your efforts, show us some code so we can build on it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible to assign variables the way u want from loop.
You can use list to store user object
This should satisfy you problem:

```
names = ['Bob', 'Guy', 'Super', 'Man']
users = []
for i in range(0,len(names), 2):
    # print(names[i], names[i+1])
    user = ClassName(names[i], names[i+1])
    users.append(user)
```

Comment: problem with a list is that i can't say ```list[0]=ClassName(names[placeholder var]_``` because it assigns the name into the list instead of the class.